# Program runs well in turbo debugger but freezes while simple execution

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm writing program for MS-DOS, that reverses all strings in the file, which path is sent as program line argument. When i run program in Turbo Dubugger it works, but when I execute it - it freezes. But how can it be? Help please. Thanks)

```
;filelab.asm
;THIS PROGRAM REVERSES FILE'S STRINGS
;PASS FILE NAME TO COMMAND LINE
;by Nikita Kunevich
;Belarus 2014
;All rights reserved

;PROBLEM - if only 1 char in str
    .model tiny
    .code
    org 100h
start:
    mov cl,cs:0080h                 ;filename length +1
    cmp cl,1
    jle cmd_error
    dec cl
    mov bl,0082h                    ;filename adress
    add bl,cl
    mov byte ptr [bx],0             ;writing 0 to the end of         filename
    mov dx,0082h

    mov ax,3D02h                    ;open file for read/write
    int 21h                         ;ax contains file identifier
    jc  read_error                  ;if file reading error

    mov bx,ax                       ;write identifier to bx
    xor cx,cx
    xor ax,ax

    mov di,offset str_buf
    LOCAL
@@fread_loop:                           ;si contains string offset
    mov cl,1h                       ;number of bytes to read
    mov ah,3Fh                      ;DOS file read func
    mov dx,di
    add dx,si
    int 21h
    push ax                         ;saving number of readen characters

    push di
    add di,si
    mov dl,byte ptr[di]
    cmp dl,0Dh                      ;EOS (if 0Ah we shouls pass through)
    pop di
    jne str_noend                   ;if not EOS skip this lines
    test si,si
    jz skip_rev                     ;if si = 0 skip reverse
    call reverse

    mov dx,2                        ;CRLF pass
    call pass_char                  
CRLF:
    add si,2
    add word ptr [filepos+2],si
    jnc skip_rev
    add word ptr [filepos],1
skip_rev:
    test si,si
    jnz not0Dh
    mov dx,1
    call pass_char
    jmp CRLF
not0Dh:
    xor si,si
    pop ax
    jmp @@fread_loop
str_noend:
    pop ax
    cmp ax,cx                       ;looking for EOF
    jl  reverse_last
    inc si
    jmp @@fread_loop
reverse_last:
    test si,si
    jz file_exit
    call reverse        ;EOF found

file_exit:
;----------------------------FILE EXIT----------------------------
    mov ah,3Eh                      ;close file, bx contains identifer
    int 21h
;----------------------------END----------------------------------      
    jmp exit
fsize_error:
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset fsize_er_mes
    int 21h
    jmp exit
cmd_error:
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset cmd_er_mes
    int 21h
    jmp exit
read_error:
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset error_mes
    int 21h
exit:
    mov ax,4c00h        
    int 21h


;--------------------DATA----------------------------
fsize_er_mes    db      "File is too big",0Dh,0Ah,'$'
access_er_mes   db      "Access denied",0Dh,0Ah,'$'
cmd_er_mes      db      "Cmd is empty!",0Dh,0Ah,'$'
error_mes       db      "Can't read the file",0Dh,0Ah,'$'
filepos         dd      0
str_buf         db      100h dup (?)
;--------------------END-----------------------------

pass_char       proc
    mov al,1                        ;CRLF pass
    xor cx,cx       
    mov ah,42h
    int 21h
    ret
pass_char endp
;reverse proc
reverse         proc
    cmp si,1
    je one_num
    push si                         ;loop var - right     border
    add si,di
    dec si
    push di                         ;loop var - left border

;reversing string
L1:
    mov al,byte ptr[di]
    mov ah,byte ptr[si]
    mov [di],ah
    mov [si],al
    dec si
    inc di
    cmp si,di
    jae L1

    pop di
    pop si

;writing reversed string back to file
;changing file offset
one_num:
    mov al,0                        ;move to the beginning of the string
    mov dx,word ptr [filepos+2]     ;in the file
    mov cx,word ptr [filepos]
    mov ah,42h
    int 21h

    mov ah,40h
    mov cx,si                       ;number of bytes to write
    mov dx,di
    int 21h
    ret
reverse endp
end start
```

Comment: You should check whether you hit EOF before doing anything else. As you have done it, you might never get to checking for EOF, hence the infinite loop.

Comment: @JesterIt didn't help

Comment: It is a COM or EXE file? Maybe the stack grows into the code?

Comment: Also, you need to zero `si` before the first read too.

Comment: @Jester I knew about that, but I didn't think that it is so important. Thanks, you saved me from hours of debugging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is pretty simple - as Jester said - i had to zero SI before the first read. My naive thought that if it equals zero in debugger it will always equal zero was wrong.